# Why wont hibernate config file parse

Tags: java, hibernate

I am building my first hibernate application on eclipse and reads in a set of SFTP credentials from an Oracle table because I want to make them configurable and not hard code them.  But when I attempt to run the application it will not parse the hibernate.cfg.xml file.  I have tried typing in all the config file and not cut and paste and I have tried changing `www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd` in the config file to `http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd`.  Why won't this work?

Here is the console output;

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse    
configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1491)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
    at name.of.package.used.retrieve.main(retrieve.java:14)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Connection refused: connect Nested exception:  
Connection refused: connect
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
    ... 2 more
```

Here is the mapping file;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                               "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping   
3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
     <class name="name.of.package.used.SFTPDetails" table="SFTP_Creds">
          <id column="SFTP_HOST" name="sftp_host">
               <generator class="assigned" />
           </id>
          <property column="SFTP_PORT" generated="never" lazy="false"
                name="sftp_port" />
          <property column="SFTP_USERNAME" generated="never" lazy="false"
                name="sftp_username" />
          <property column="SFTP_PASSWORD" generated="never" lazy="false"
                name="sftp_password" />
          <property column="SFTP_HOSTKEY" generated="never" lazy="false"
                name="sftp_hostkey" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This is the **hibernate.cfg.xml** file;

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
     <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</property>
     <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1523:TRNG</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
     <property   
    name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
      <mapping resource="sftpcreds.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My main Java file that I am running the application is;

```
package name.of.package.used;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.mapping.List;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class retrieve {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
     Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
     cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");// populates the data of the configuration file

    // creating seession factory object
    SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();

    // creating session object
    Session session = factory.openSession();

    // creating transaction object
    Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();

    Query query = session.createQuery("from SFTPCreds");
    java.util.List list = query.list();
    System.out.println(list);
    t.commit();
    session.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `hibernate.cfg.cml` located in your project?

Comment: @Jens.  Located in the src folder as is the package and the mapping file

Comment: Try to use `cfg.configure(retrieve.class.getResource("hibernate.cfg.xml"))`

Comment: @Jens.  Tried your suggestion and now console output is log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1438)
 at uk.gov.renfrewshire.edrms.retrieve.main(retrieve.java:14)

Comment: Then remove the suggestion. Can it be tht the name of the property must be `hibernate.connection.url` instead of `connection.url`

Comment: @Jens tried adding hibernate. to all the config file property tags but made no difference

Comment: @user2696089 answer added, try once more, try hitting urls

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it is your dtd reference: http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping
3.0.dtd

This is down and obsolete You should use ttp://www.jboss.org/dtd/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd

Comment: Thanks rparree.  I tried this and changed http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping
3.0.dtd in the mapping xml file to http://www.jboss.org/dtd/hibernate/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd and also changed http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd in the config xml file to http://www.jboss.org/dtd/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd but i'm afraid the console output is the same

Comment: Is there a proxy to the internet?

Comment: Yes the organisation has a proxy but I am not allowed to change anything

Comment: You probably have to set the following arguments when starting java: -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 (change with your values)

Comment: Thanks rparree.  I had to take 2 days annual leave at short notice so hence the late reply.  Where do I make the change -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 (change with your values)?  Is this a Tomcat configuration?

Comment: It depends on your installation (rpm, deb, zip/tar). For the latter use the  setenv.sh|bat in your CATALINA_BASE/bin and set the JAVA_OPTS

Comment: I am a little farther forward as it "appears" to be parsing configuration file after I chnaged a few things, but now it is not mapping.  What am I doing wrong?  The table holding the values is named SFTP_CREDS and the Java object class is called SFTPCreds with the mapping file named sftpcreds.hbm.xml and the entry in the configuration file is <mapping resource="sftpcreds.hbm.xml" /> but I keep generating an error saying SFTPCreds is not mapped [from SFTPCreds] or if I chnage the query to "from sftpcreds" error says sftpcreds is not mapped [from sftpcreds]

Answer (score 0):

This means the `hibernate.dtd` cannot be resolved - its resolution is attempted on the server. The `dtd` is contained in the jars files - see [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=949031) and [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/73208-how-to-configure-hibernate-cfg-xml-to-work-offline) for how to resolve it.

Also  try changing the path from: `hibernate.org/dtd` to `hibernate.sourceforge.net`

it means that the XML parser is having a problem trying to access your DTD definition. So first thing to do is to see if you can browse the url for it directly and also check your proxy settings. In my case, I changed it

from

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

I think you can also try using "http://www.jboss.org/dtd/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd". It seems like hibernate.org fwds to the jboss location anyways.

Comment: Thanks I tried what you suggested and what rparree suggested but the problem remains

Comment: I placed http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd directly in my browser URL bar and a warning appeared stating it could not access the file but when I tried it again it prompted me to open or save and by clicking open the DTD opened in visual studio.  When I placed http://www.jboss.org/dtd/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd directly in the browser URL it prompted me to open or save and clicking open again the file opened in visual studio straight away